# Linux find files with string and replace

Tags: linux, perl, find, replace, xargs

I have some websites that have been attacked and infected with malware.

There are 800+ files that need to be updated and the string is exactly the same in each file.

What I want to do is find all the files that have the malware, and then delete the offending string from the file.

I have found some command line scripts which work fine when tested on a basic string:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/string_to_find//g;' test-file.php
```

and when combined into the find command:

find . -type f | xargs grep 'string_to_find' -sl | xargs perl -pi -w -e 's/string_to_find//g;'

Now my problem is getting that to work on the string which is an extremely long and and complex string:

```
<?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset($eva1fYlbakBcVSir)) {$eva1fYlbakBcVSir = "random_string_7365_characters_long";$eva1tYlbakBcVSir = "string_of_encoded_characters";$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "string_of_encoded_characters";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = "string_of_encoded_characters";$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = "string_of_encoded_characters";$eva1tYldokBcVSjr=$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYldakBoVS1r);$eva1tYldakBcVSjr=$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYlbakBcVSir);$eva1tYidakBcVSjr = $eva1tYldakBcVSjr(chr(2687.5*0.016), $eva1fYlbakBcVSir);$eva1tYXdakAcVSjr = $eva1tYidakBcVSjr[0.031*0.061];$eva1tYidokBcVSjr = $eva1tYldakBcVSjr(chr(3625*0.016), $eva1tYidokBoVSjr);$eva1tYldokBcVSjr($eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.016*(7812.5*0.016)],$eva1tYidokBcVSjr[62.5*0.016],$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.061*0.031]));$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir.$eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "string_of_encoded_characters";$eva1tYlbakBcVSir = "string_of_encoded_characters";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = "string_of_encoded_characters";$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir.$eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir;} ?>
```

Now, when I try the search and replace with the full string (escaping all the special characters) I get this result:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @error_reporting in string at -e line 1.
Name "main::error_reporting" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do or is the string impossible to capture? Do I need to escape the @ symbol differently? (I escaped with a \ and that didn't work)

Any help - I am a novice with bash and perl

Comment: FAQ http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-can-I-quote-a-variable-to-use-in-a-regex-

Comment: thanks daxim - I don't want to learn perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The statement was correct, I had just missed escaping some characters.

So in answer to my question, the answer is:

Yes - the method used is correct and works in achieving the desired result
Yes - The @ symbol must also be escaped

Escape the string correctly and the statement works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `\@` ought to work, but you've got other problems too: `<?` matches an optional `<`, for example, not the sequence `<?`. According to `man perlre`, the following ought to work:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/\Q<?php \E@\Qerror_reporting...//g'
```

The `\Q` turns off all special regexp meanings, allowing you to search for an exact string without quoting every metacharacter. The \E restores the special meaning temporarily, but since `@` is isolated it is not interpreted as the beginning of an array name. You'll have to surround each `@` and `$` the same way. And then of course, do check that this works properly! Good luck.

**Edit:** In truth I would recommend replacing your one-liner with a simple script. Define the string you want to search for, ensuring that no unwanted variable substitution occurs (print it out to make sure); disable all special characters with `quotemeta()` to disable their regular-expression meaning; and apply to the input. That's if the string is really EXACTLY the same; if the "random_string..." differs from place to place, you need to build your RE more carefully. In any case, it'll make your life easier if you write a 5-line perl script, get it to work on one file, and then use the find/xargs method to apply it everywhere.

Comment: so can I just surround the whole string with \Q ... \E? except the one occurrence of @

Comment: No, you cannot. The `$` need to be escaped too. See the manpage.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to back out to the command-line and use `sed`. It's built for precisely this type of problem. Here is a good place to get started:
[IBM Developerworks SED by example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-sed1/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions have other features that could make this task easier. If you don't have any valid code with variables that start with `$evalfYl`, then you can use a much simpler regular expression with less to escape:

```
perl -pi -w -e \
's/<\?php \@error_reporting\(0\);if \(!isset(\$evalYl.*?} \?>//g' \
 test-file.php
```

where `.*?` will match any characters up to the next occurrence of "} ?>" in the string.

Comment: Ok, but it wouldn't matter anyway if I did because it would need to be preceded by @error_reporting(0)... anyway wouldn't it? Also, you have escaped the @ so I do need to escape this in perl?